# Weighing an elephant

Tags: lateral-thinking, weighing

Here's another classic I couldn't find on the site:

**How can you determine the weight of an elephant without using a scale?**

Comment: @MarkN You want to post that as an answer? I was wondering what kind of crazy solutions the people would come up with.

Comment: @MarkN and how much is this standard elephant?

Comment: Simply ask the elephant. (and assume a spherical elephant)

Comment: @MarkN What if he didn't know?

Comment: @mmking then you ask another elephant (preferably one that knows)! Otherwise resort to my plan B

Comment: @MarkN that won't work - consider the elephant is male, then he won't know his weight.  Now if it's a female, she'll lies about it.

Comment: I know a guy who does research into exactly this topic (well, substitute "cow" for "elephant"). Pity I only arrived once the question was closed - I might've been able to cite some of his academic papers!

Comment: Fling him into deep outer space. Then you'll know for certain that his weight is 0.

Comment: get a large rotating disk, with known mass.  Set it rotating at known speed  with the elephant at centre.  Elephant then walks to edge, disk slows to conserve angular momentum, which is now partly in the elephant.  Then you need to do some maths with moments of angular intertia, which is knwn for a disk, and a mass at the edge, and can be estimated for a roughly spherical elephant in the centre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the canonical answer, via the Archimedes Principle:

> Put the elephant onto a large boat, and mark the water level that the boat sinks to. Then, take the elephant out and put a bunch of marked weights onto the boat until it reaches the same water level. Add up the masses of the weights to get the weight of the elephant.

Answer (score 5):

Place an object of known mass a fixed distance away from the elephant, and measure the gravitational attraction the elephant exerts on the object. This will let you compute the elephant's mass, and therefore its weight.

Comment: How do you measure gravitational attraction without a spring scale?

Comment: I was picturing something like the fixed mass is hanging from the ceiling on a string, and you measure how much it deviates from vertical.

Comment: Oh. That might actually make sense.

Comment: the original used wires that twisted, and two sets of giant balls.

Answer (score 3):

You could just do what the [Imperial system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_units) did and make it a new unit of measurement.

i.e - I would like to purchase 0.002 elephants of chocolate please!

For every new elephant king that appears, we simply change the unit to suit it properly.

---

Alternative answer:
Take the elephant into space, and calculate its gravitational pull on a know mass object (using the universal gravitation equation.)

Answer (score 3):

Put the elephant on one end of a seasaw with a known weight at the other and keep adding or removing weight until it is in balance?

Alternatively, submerge the elephant in water in a pool that is of known volume and measure the increase in water level.

Comment: You're basically using the seesaw the same way you'd use a two-pan balance, though, which is also a scale.

Comment: The water submersion one works, though.

Comment: volume != weight

Comment: Yes, however 1 cubic centimeter of water weights 1 gram so conversion is possible,

Comment: How? You will get the weight for the volume of water that is occupied by the elephant. not the weight of the elephant. If an elephant was made of water, this would indeed work as all you would need to know to weight the elephant is his volume, that however is not the case... I might be missing something but this seems wrong and you aren't the only one who gave this answer. Note that this is very different than the Archimedes Principle stated by Joe Z.

Comment: Fill the pool to the brim.  Let the elephant swim in it.  Some water will overflow.  Take it out.  Check how much water you need to refill it.  The elephant has a lower mass density than water.  But the excess volume will remain above water level.  The displaced water weights exactly as much as the elephant.  When you refill, measure the water in weight, not volume.

Comment: Correct Florian F.  Most mammals are a very high percentage water anyway so the displacement is going to have a fairly high amount of accuracy but the overflow technique would add certainly provided the elephant swimming didn't push too much extra water out.

Comment: And provided the elephant doesn't swim too high in the water too. The density of an elephant is probably about the same as a person's, $1.0-1.1 kg/dm^3$. We could assume it's 1 and ask the elephant nicely to stand in a container of water with the end of its trunk just above the surface.

Answer (score 1):

Take a truck who can support a known weight.

-If the truck can support it, take another truck who can support a little less weight.

-If he can't, take one who can support a little more.

Reproduce until you find the perfect truck and you get his supported weight.

Comment: That's a lot of trucks you're going to break.

Comment: Hmm... that's clever, but usually you can only get a measurement to within 100 or 500 pounds that way.

Comment: Well, this is important, all the truck constructors will provides very specific trucks ! WE NEED TO KNOW !

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the elephant is not going to be very happy if you keep putting him on trucks that break underneath him.

Comment: Nobody said that the elephant need to be alive...

Comment: Must trucks rated at 7.5 tonnes are physically capable of carrying more weight than their taxation or licencing class.

Comment: Those are very specific trucks who can't carry more than what it is specified.

Comment: There is a solution using a vehicle though although the maths would be very complex.  Load the elephant and then let the tyres down until the wheel is resting on the road.  Unload the elephant then measure the pressure remaining in the tyres.  Let more air out of the tyres until the wheels are again resting on the road.  Measure the pressure of the tyres once more and use this pressure difference plus the vehicle unlaiden weight as the basis for your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

My sister came up with this one:

1. Make a small cut on the elephant.
2. Pump out all of its blood.
3. Cut the elephant into pieces and weigh each piece (by putting it in a tank of water)
4. Weigh the bloody stuff. (by putting it in a bag with negligible weight and then putting it in a tank of water)
5. Add up all the weights.

Comment: Your sister is a bloodthirsty little thing :-o

Comment: @randal'thor Well, at first, she was just going to go ahead and cut it up, but she was afraid that if she didn't pump out the blood first, she would miss the weight of the bloddy stuff.

Comment: She couldn't just imagine a really big tank of water? "No, that's ridiculous. Let's go Dexter on this pachyderm."

Comment: @EngineerToast She said she didn't want to drown the elephant. She didn't want to see the elephant suffer at the bottom of a tank and figured that her method would kill the elephant faster. And besides, she was going to cook the chunks of elephant meat when she was done.

Comment: If you're going to do that, why not just open the fridge door, put the elephant in, and close it?

Comment: @JoeZ. You mean cut up the frozen chunks of elephant? I guess that would work too. But frozen meat is a lot harder to cut up.

Answer (score 0):

Elephants are known for their patience so find yourself a beach chair, some tanning lotion, LOTS of beer and a good pair of sunglasses. (Snacks are a plus but avoid peanuts as they may render the whole thing useless)

Once you are set , start the timer on your watch and observe the elephant. Once the elephant is tired of you staring at it and leaves, stop your timer. And you will know how much that elephants waits.

Get it ? get it?